# How to find maximum value from comma separated value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to find maximum value from comma separated string value using xslt 1.0. Below is my input file sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<product>
    <item>1,2.5,3.6,4</item>
</product>

Expected output:
<product>
     <item>4</item>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="item"> 
    <xsl:variable name="items">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($items)/item">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </item>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:
This could be simplified if your processor supports the EXSLT extension functions str:tokenize() and/or math:max().

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that doesn't use any extension functions. I'm not sure about its performance, but maybe it will help.

If you can use XSLT 2.0 (or the EXSLT extension functions mentioned in another answer) this becomes super easy.

**XML Input** (Slightly modified to change the original sort order.)

```
<product>
    <item>1,2.5,4,3.6</item>
</product>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="getMax">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="normalize-space()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getMax">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="firstNbr" select="number(substring-before(concat($string,','),','))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="secondNbr">
            <xsl:if test="contains($string,',')">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-before(concat(substring-after($string,','),','),','))"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="remainingNbrs" select="substring-after(substring-after($string,','),',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="modString">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$firstNbr > $secondNbr">
                    <!--Move $firstNbr to the end.-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$remainingNbrs"/>
                    <xsl:if test="string($remainingNbrs)">,</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$firstNbr"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!--Drop $firstNbr.-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$secondNbr"/>
                    <xsl:if test="string($remainingNbrs)">,</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$remainingNbrs"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string($secondNbr)">
                <xsl:call-template name="getMax">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$modString"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$firstNbr"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<product>
   <item>4</item>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable reply, I resolved above issue using below stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxml">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="fields">
            <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'125,192,152.50,1600,145,169,170'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <final>
            <xsl:value-of select="msxml:node-set($fields)/field[not(. &lt; msxml:node-set($fields)/field)][1]"/>
        </final>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="SimpleStringLoop">
        <xsl:param name="input"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="v" select="substring-before(concat($input, ','),',')"/>
            <field>
                <xsl:value-of select="$v"/>
            </field>
            <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```